# WordPress: Add a language attribute to the shortcode for translation

Tags: wordpress, plugins, translation, shortcode

I'm trying to give my shortcode the ability to switch language.

For example `[my-form lang="fr_FR"]` will load my French mo file and display the form in french. And the same for others language:  `[my-form lang="en_US"]` will display the form in english.

The .mo files are ok, my plugin administration display the correct language according the worpress language setting. To do that, i put this line in my plugin main file ('plugins_loaded' hook):

```
load_plugin_textdomain( 'my-plugin', false, basename( dirname( __ FILE __ ) ) . '/languages' );
```

In the shortcode function, i call this:

```
load_textdomain( 'my-plugin', $pathtomofile )
```

`$pathtomofile` is adapted according the language shorcode attribute: 'fr_FR' will call french mo file, 'en_US' call english mo file...

**The problem is:** It works for an english wordpress installation switched to 'français' when shortcode call 'en_US'. It doesn't work when i switch back the setting to 'english (United States)' and i try to call 'fr_FR' with the shortcode.
My mind will explode, can you explain this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In reality, i needed to remove the WP registered translation:

```
global $l10n;
if (isset($l10n['my-plugin'])){
    unset($l10n['my-plugin']);
}
load_textdomain( 'my-plugin', $pathtomofile )
```